# Using decompiled code to assess string for being blank?

Tags: android, kotlin

#1) this Kotlin code written in Android Studio

```
fun test(s: String){ if (s =="") /*do something*/ }
```

gets decompiled to

```
public final void test(@NotNull String s) {
  Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(s, "s");
  Intrinsics.areEqual(s, "");
}
```

#2) this Kotlin code

```
fun test(s: String){ if (s.isEmpty()) /*do something*/ }
```

get decompiled to

```
public final void test(@NotNull String s) {
  Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(s, "s");
  CharSequence var2 = (CharSequence)s;
  boolean var3 = false;
  if (var2.length() == 0) {
  }
}
```

the `s.isEmpty()` creates a `CharSequence` and `boolean`.  Does this make the s=="" a better method?
Most recommendations on SO questions are to use the isEmpty() method (without any explanation as to why).  If this is the case, why?

Comment: I assume you can ascertain this by yourself by creating 2 methods, one that checks the string using == and one that checks using isEmpty... call this in a for loop for maybe 1000 iterations. Get the current time in milliseconds before the for loop executes and after it executes. Minus the result for the start and end time and you should be able to see which one takes longer if any

Comment: I suppose there's also memory churn to be concerned about as well. Add that to the fact that benchmarking is not my strong suit. And also, I guess I'm looking for thoughts on if my analysis of the decompiled code is accurate.

Comment: Perhaps but fundamentally that is how benchmarking works. Time taken to execute a given method, and you get a better average executing it multiple times. And what's better then a concrete number, versus the assumption more lines of code == longer execution times. I mean what does `Intrinsics.areEqual` do, but offhand it seems like it would be faster

Comment: To add to my comment you have decompiled kotlin to its java equivalent, there is still the the decompile from java to java byte code and that might tell more of a story. But again you would need to be able to interpret it correctly

Comment: All good points.  like you said, the `Intrinsics.areEqual` might hide some additional overhead.

Comment: These are going to perform essentially the same.  The one and only reason to pick one over the other is whether or not they are _clearer to read_.